# Passing arguments to python script in Azure Devops

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to pass a system variable to the python script from azure devops. This is what I currently have in Yaml file:

```
- script: pytest test/test_pipeline.py 
          --$(global_variable) 
          --junitxml=$(Build.StagingDirectory)/test_pipeline-results.xml
          displayName: 'Testing Pipeline'
          condition: always()
```

The variable I need in my script is `$(global_variable)`. The variable contains a value of `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`. It is the global variable. I am getting an error message as `"unrecognised arguments"` when I run the job.

Any help to tackle this will be helpful.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Complete log:

```
`##[section]Starting: Testing Pipeline
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.151.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Script contents:
pytest test/test_pipeline.py --my_param="/home/vsts/work/1/s" --junitxml=/home/vsts/work/1/a/test_pipeline-results.xml
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/64fb4a65-90de-42d5-bfb3-58cc8aa174e3.sh
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --my_param=/home/vsts/work/1/s
  inifile: None
  rootdir: /home/vsts/work/1/s

##[error]Bash exited with code '4'.
##[section]Finishing: Testing Pipeline`
```

Comment: You can try with Python Script task instead. In `Arguments` you can pass variable in it.

Comment: I did try that as well.Something like this:

  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    condition: always()
    displayName: "Testing Pipleline For Test Cases"
    inputs:
      arguments: $(global_variable)
      testResultsFiles: $(Build.StagingDirectory)/test_pipeline-results.xml
      testRunTitle: Test Pipeline

Comment: Where you define the `global_variable`?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk at the very beginning. I also echoed the value just to be sure. It does stores what I want.

Comment: Do you mind update with the complete log in your question?

Comment: `Exit code 4` means that sorry, we could not open the file. And also, according to the log, the script content you write is `--my_param="/home/vsts/work/1/s"`, `--my_param` is a invalid argument which caused the error `unrecognized arguments`.

Comment: Why did you specified it here?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Pardon my limited knowledge on the subject. Also Could you please elaborate your question. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry for my short question. In fact, `--my_param` is not a valid argument in script. That's why you received unrecognized arguments error. What's does this argument mean in this script? As I understood, you want to use command to run `pytest` for `test_pipeline-results.xml` .

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I see what you mean now. I wrote  --my_param because I found a page where it was written to pass arguments like this. I have lost the link to the page because I have been working on this since yesterday.

Comment: I have also tried to write my code similar to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/blob/master/tools/ci_build/github/azure-pipelines/azure-pipelines-py-packaging.yml): 

` - task: PythonScript@0
      displayName: 'Download test data'
      inputs:
        scriptPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/tools/ci_build/github/download_test_data.py'
        arguments: --test_data_url $(TestDataUrl) --build_dir $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
        pythonInterpreter: '/usr/bin/python3'
        workingDirectory: $(Build.BinariesDirectory)
`
But this fails as well.

Comment: Do you mind us talk with chat? I might know what's wrong you are facing, but difficult to write it in comment because of limitation.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197560/for-python-test

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT sure. I followed the link. Please help me understand the chat system. I have never used it before.

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately, I don't have 20 points to chat on stackoverflow

Comment: (aha) I vote this question, so you have added 5 points :-)  Let's talk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197563/discussion-between-natalie-and-merlin-liang-msft).

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT You should get a request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tried to write a simple sample for you refer.

In your `.py` file, please use `add_argument` to read in the command line parameter. In this issue, this command line parameter comes from your task specified.

`A.py` file:

```
import argparse 

def parse_argument():
       parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ForTest!")
       parse.add_argument("-test_data")
       parse.add_argument("-build_dir")
```

And then, in `PythonScript@0` task:

```
scriptPath: ‘A.py’
argument: -test_data $(myVariable1) -build_dir $(myVariable2)
```

`myVariable1` and `myVariable2` are all my customized variable. You can all use environment variable.

Since in python script, `add_argument` is used to read in the parameter which from command line. So it can receive the value from `Argument` specified.

In addition, for the issue which in your question, I think you’d better delete the content from your script: `--my_param="/home/vsts/work/1/s"` and try again. Because `--my_param` could not the valid argument for `pytest`.

Hope can help you.

Comment: Thanks! Don't you know about arguments with spaces in them?