# Passing azure secret variables to pytest in pipeline?

Tags: python, azure, environment-variables, pipeline

We are running integration tests, written in Python, in Azure Pipeline. These tests access a database, and the credentials for accessing the database are stored in a variable group in Azure, including secret variables. This is the part of the yaml file, where the integration tests are started:

```
jobs:
- job: IntegrationTests
  variables:
    - group: <some_variable_group>

 - script: |
       pdm run pytest \
         --variables "$VARIABLE_FILE" \
         --test-run-title="$TEST_TITLE" \
         --napoleon-docstrings \
         --doctest-modules \
         --color=yes \
         --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml \
         integration

     env:
       DB_USER: $(SMDB_USER)
       DB_PASSWORD: $(SMDB_PASSWORD)
       DB_HOST: $(SMDB_HOST)
       DB_DATABASE: $(SMDB_DATABASE)
```

The problem is, that we cannot read the value of SMDB_PASSWORD, as it is a secret variable. In order to use the secret variables, it is advised to use arguments in a PythonScript task (like here: [Passing arguments to python script in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57374248/passing-arguments-to-python-script-in-azure-devops))
but i am not aware how to modify this script to be defines PythonScript, as it includes using pdm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually according to docs they should be available as env variables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-secret-variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbash#use-a-secret-variable-in-the-ui

```
environ.get('DB_USER')
```

edit: repro:

```
python -c "import os, base64; print(base64.b64encode(bytes(os.environ.get('TEST_PLAIN'), 'ascii')))"
```

Comment: They are, but except the secret variables ("DB_PASSWORD' in this case). When environ.get('DB_PASSWORD') is executed, '***' is the result.

Comment: what you are saying is not true ;) if you simply print it to stdout - right, azure devops will replace it with `***`, but in the python code you are actually getting the right value

Comment: What i do is printing the result from the execution of the integration test, the python code. I have the following code : password = os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD") and then assert password == "temp_test". The execution prints - AssertionError: assert '***' == 'temp_test'

Comment: right, because it will remove secret from STDOUT, this simply means that assertion failed, if DB_PASSWORD would equal to `temp_test` assertion would not fail

Comment: Actually you were right!!! I had an error in the code.